# Complex queries in neo4j embedded java

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api

How do I perform

```
MATCH (p:Person:Actor)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movies{name:"ABC"}) RETURN p.name;
```

In neo4j embedded Java . detailed explanation of the code would be of great help.
**note:** I want to do this in native Java api not in cypher. It is supposed to have around 100000 nodes

Answer (score 1):

You can execute Cypher queries with:

```
GraphDatabaseService db = ...;

// from version 2.2.x onwards
db.execute("your cypher statement");

// before version 2.2.x
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db)
engine.execute("your cypher statement");
```

If you're using Neo4j before v2.2, please note that `ExecutionEngine` is meant to be instantiated as a singleton, so that execution plans will be properly cached.

If you have got strong performance constraints, might want to play with [`TraversalDescription`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) and customize the many available parameters and define a traversal callback if needed. The key is to ensure you traverse as little node as required.

You should know though that Cypher execution is being more and more performant, last version (2.2) brings lots of improvements.

Comment: Well, no hard guess here. 2.2 version brings lots of improvements regarding Cypher optimizations.

Comment: Edited my initial answer to provide you with the alternative, aka TraversalDescription.

Comment: And isn't ExecutionEngine deprecated the official document says to use dB.execute() where dB is Instance of GraphDatabaseService.

Comment: Argh, true, this has been introduced in 2.2.x afaik. Will edit my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Label person = DynamicLabel.label("Person");
for(Node p : GlobalGraphOperations.at(gdb).getAllNodesWithLabel(person))
{
    RelationshipType actedIn =  DynamicRelationshipType.withName("ACTED_IN");
    if(p.hasRelationship(actedIn, Direction.OUTGOING))
    {
        Node m = p.getSingleRelationship(actedIn, Direction.OUTGOING).getEndNode();
        Label person = DynamicLabel.label("Movies");
        if(m.hasLabel(movies) && m.getProperty("name", null) == "ABC")
        {
            return p.getProperty("name");
        }
    }
}
```